# Node.js / express - using passport with redis, getting session unauthorized

Tags: node.js, express, redis, passport.js

I'm trying to use redis with express to create a user login and session. I test the route using this curl script:

```
curl -d 'email=testEmail&password=testPass' http://localhost:3000/users/session
```

When I do this, passport works fine through serialization, and then it returns http 302. I haven't figured out what it does after serialization, but when I try it in the browser with my login html form instead of curl, It shows me "Unauthorized" 401, and I don't see any of my console logs. Here's my app.js:

```
var express = require('express')
    , fs = require('fs')
    , cons = require('consolidate')
    , http = require('http')
    , flash = require('connect-flash')
    , passport = require('passport')
    , RedisStore = require( "connect-redis" )(express) //for sessions (instead of MemoryStore)
    , redis = require('redis')
    , env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development'
    , config = require('./config/config')[env]
    , db = redis.createClient(config.db.port, config.db.host);

db.select(config.db.users)
db.auth(config.db.auth);

var app = express();

//require passport strategies (see code block below)
require('./config/passport')(passport, config, app)

app.use('/assets', express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.use('/', express.static(__dirname + '/'));
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'html');

app.configure(function(){
    app.set('config', config);
    app.set('db', db);
    app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
    app.engine('.html', cons.swig);
    app.use(express.logger('dev'))
    app.use(express.favicon(__dirname + '/public/img/favicon.ico'));
    app.use(express.cookieParser())
    app.use(express.bodyParser()) //enables req.body
    app.use(express.methodOverride()) //enables app.put and app.delete (can also just use app.post)
    app.use(express.session({
        secret: 'topsecret',
        cookie: {secure: true, maxAge:86400000},
        store: new RedisStore({
            client:db,
            secret:config.db.auth
        })
    }));

    app.use(flash())
    app.use(passport.initialize())
    app.use(passport.session())
    app.use(app.router)
});

// Bootstrap routes
require('./config/routes')(app, passport);

http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
    console.log("Express server listening on port " + app.get('port')+', mode='+env);
});
```

And the session POST route:

```
app.post('/users/session', passport.authenticate('local', {successRedirect: '/', failureFlash: 'Invalid email or password.', successFlash: 'Welcome!'}), users.session);
```

I could only really find examples of passport with mongodb, so I'm not sure about the following. I attempt to find a user, but I'm not sure about the callbacks or what passport is doing with the user info when I return done:

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy({ usernameField: 'email', passwordField: 'password' },
    function(email, password, done) {

        var db = app.get('db')
        var multi = db.multi();

        db.get('email:'+email, function(err, uid){
            if (err) { console.log(err); return err }
            if (!uid) { console.log('no uid found'); return null }

            console.log('found '+uid)
            db.hgetall('uid:'+uid, function(err, user){
                if (err) { console.log(err); return err }
                if (!user) {
                    console.log('unkwn usr')
                    return done(null, false, { message: 'Unknown user' })
                }

                if (password != user.password) {
                    console.log('invalid pwd')
                    return done(null, false, { message: 'Invalid password' })
                }
                console.log('found user '+user) //I see this fine with curl, but no logs with browser
                return done(null, user)
            });
        });      
    }
))
```

Passport serialization:

```
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    console.log('passport serializing...'+user.name)
    done(null, user.name) //no idea what happens to it after this. returns a 302 with curl, and 401 with browser
})
```

Why does this act differently with a browser than with curl? Any help or comments much appreciated!

Comment: Difference is that your browser might be sending a (left-over) session cookie. Try running your browser in Incognito/Private mode. Also, do you implement `passport.deserializeUser`? If not, you should.

Comment: Tried it with incognito mode and deleted cache/ cookies, same results. I haven't gotten to the point where I'd need the deserializeUser yet, I believe that's for removing the session, correct? It's still showing "Unauthorized" when I use a browser, and none of my console.logs show up.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out! To use passport with *any* database (not just mongo), I would recommend trying it with a dummy user first. Here's what I did.

Login Form (login.html):

```
<form method="post" action="http://localhost:3000/users/session" name="loginform">
    <input id="login_input_username" type="text" name="email" />
    <input id="login_input_password" type="password" name="password" autocomplete="off" />
    <input type="submit"  name="login" value="Submit" /> 
</form>
```

Routing (route.js):

```
app.post('/users/session', passport.authenticate('local'), 
    function(req, res){
        res.end('success!');
    });
```

Passport Local Strategy setup (passport.js):

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy({ usernameField: 'email', passwordField: 'password' },
    function(email, password, done) {
        //find user in database here
        var user = {id: 1, email:'test', password:'pass'};
        return done(null, user);
    }
));

passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    //serialize by user id
    done(null, user.id)
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
    //find user in database again
    var user = {id: 1, email:'test', password:'pass'};
    done(null, user);
})
```

Although I'm wondering if it's necessary to find user in my database twice, or if I'm using deserialize incorrectly.

Comment: The purpose of `serializeUser` is to store some form of identifying information for the user in the session; `deserializeUser` uses that information to retrieve the full user information again. You can either store the entire user object in the session (so you don't have to query the database for it again), or store an id (in which case you do need to query the database in `deserializeUser` to resolve the id to a user record). It depends though if the user object can be store in the session as-is.

Comment: (also, if you store the entire user object, it might differ from the user information in the database if that has changed since the last time the user's data has been serialized into the session)

Comment: Hmm, if I query the database for de-serializing, and the user HAS changed something (say their profile name), then the serialized cookie version won't match what's in the db. So doesn't that mean the session will be invalid (in the latter approach)? and wouldn't we want to refrain from querying the db on deserialize?

Comment: If you only store the (unique) user id in the session, and query the database for each connection to retrieve the user information from the database (using that id), you are guaranteed that the user information matches what's in the database for that user with every request. The cookie only stores the session-id, but the session *contents* will be stored in Redis.